# Antd + Dayjs: TypeError: clone.weekday is not a function

Tags: reactjs, antd, react-hook-form, dayjs

I upgraded the Ant Design version from 4 to 5 and replaced Moment with Day.js, then encountered this error.

```
const {
    field,
    fieldState: { error },
  } = useController({ name: name, control: control });

  return (
    <div>
      <RangePicker
        style={error ? errorStyle : defaultStyle}
        format={customFormatList}
        suffixIcon={<BsCalendarDate className="text-lg" />}
        value={field.value}
        onChange={(e) => {
          field.onChange(e);
        }}
        onBlur={() => {
          field.onBlur();
        }}
        onCalendarChange={(e) => {
          field.onChange(e);
        }}
        {...rest}
      />
      {error && <p className="text-sm text-[#ff4d4f]">{error.message}</p>}
    </div>
  );
```

Then, I set default value with react-hook-form:

```
 const { control, handleSubmit, setValue, watch } = useForm<SearchFormInputValues>({
    defaultValues: {
      requestDate: [dayjs(), dayjs()],
    },
    resolver: yupResolver(schema),
  });

...
<DateRangePicker
   name="requestDate"
   control={control}
   placeholder={["dd-mm-yyyy", "dd-mm-yyyy"]}/>
```

It displays the correct date I need, but when I click to edit, an error occurs above. When I click the delete button next to it and select the date again, there will be no error.

[image: Bug image 1]
[image: Bug image 2]
I tried to fix this error by adding the following lines of code, but it's not working:

```
import dayjs from "dayjs";
import weekday from "dayjs/plugin/weekday";
import localeData from "dayjs/plugin/localeData";

dayjs.extend(weekday);
dayjs.extend(localeData);
dayjs.locale("en");
dayjs.locale("vi");
```

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: Please see https://ant.design/docs/react/use-custom-date-library#antd-moment-webpack-plugin

Comment: I want to replace Moment with Dayjs

Answer (score 13):

You have to add this code to your index app file

```
import dayjs from 'dayjs'
import advancedFormat from 'dayjs/plugin/advancedFormat'
import customParseFormat from 'dayjs/plugin/customParseFormat'
import localeData from 'dayjs/plugin/localeData'
import weekday from 'dayjs/plugin/weekday'
import weekOfYear from 'dayjs/plugin/weekOfYear'
import weekYear from 'dayjs/plugin/weekYear'

dayjs.extend(customParseFormat)
dayjs.extend(advancedFormat)
dayjs.extend(weekday)
dayjs.extend(localeData)
dayjs.extend(weekOfYear)
dayjs.extend(weekYear)
```

Comment: Your solution worked correctly, but it would be good if describe what is the problem and how it helps to fix the problem.

Comment: This took me a long time to find. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

```
import * as dayjs from 'dayjs'
import * as isLeapYear from 'dayjs/plugin/isLeapYear' // import plugin
import 'dayjs/locale/zh-cn' // import locale

dayjs.extend(isLeapYear) // use plugin
dayjs.locale('zh-cn') // use locale
```

I think it help you
Could you add code into file index.tsx or index.js of root app

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).